# Is it possible to get SMS sending result from other Activity?

Tags: android, sms

I have a function in my application to allow user to send sms then logging it's usage. But instead of developing our own SMSHandler, we opt to let user choose whatever SMS app they want to use. It all seems fine but I couldn't find a way to getting response from the other SMS application like delivered PendingIntent mention in this article.

http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesfullapplications/241-sms-messaging-in-android-send-and-receive

Is there a way to do it? This is how I request SMS Activity.

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello SMS"); 
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```